# PDO form add to database: Array number is added rather than the text it represents

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I'm new to PHP and PDO. I've managed to get the PDO to add the form data to a mysql database when the submit button is clicked.
The problem I am having is drop down box which selects and displays the data from another database table. When this is added to the databases rather than displaying the selected option 'Top, Hat or Coat' it instead displays '0, 1, 2'.

HTML Code (with some PHP):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <?PHP include_once("addProduct.php");?>
        <form method="post" action="">
            Product Name: <input type="text" id="productName" name="productName" /><br />

            Catagory: 
            <?php
                mysql_connect("localhost", "root","") or die(mysql_error());
                mysql_select_db("web_scripting") or die(mysql_error());
                $query = "SELECT id,category FROM catagory_table";
                $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()."[".$query."]");
            ?>                                  
            <select type="text" id="category" name="category">
            <?php 
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'>'".$row['category']."'</option>";
                }
            ?>  </select><br />

            Stock: <input type="number" id="stock" name="stock" /><br />

            Cost: <input type="number" id="cost" name="cost" /><br />

            <input type="submit" value="add"> <br />

            <?PHP   
                $query = "SELECT * FROM product_table";
                $result = $odb->query($query);
                if($result->rowCount() > 0) {
                    foreach($result as $item) {
                    echo($item['name'] . " , " . $item['category'] . " , " . $item['stock'] . " , " . $item['cost'] . "<br />");
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
```

PHP Code:

```
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$db = "web_scripting";
$pass = "";

$odb = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $host . ";dbname=" . $db, $user, $pass);

if(isset($_POST['productName'])) {
    $productName = $_POST['productName'];
    $category = $_POST['category'];
    $stock = $_POST['stock'];
    $cost = $_POST['cost'];
    $q = "INSERT INTO product_table(name, category, stock, cost) VALUES(:name, :category, :stock, :cost);";
    $query = $odb->prepare($q);
    $results = $query->execute(array(
        ":name" => $productName,
        ":category" => $category,
        ":stock" => $stock,
        ":cost" => $cost
    ));
}
?>
```

Comment: `print_r` your $_`POST` array and see what you get there. Value of `value` attribute of `option` is passed to `$_POST`, not the text.

Answer (score 1):

I would say this is correct, your database is saving the id of the category which is what you want. The name of the category can be found by querying the category table for that id. This is relational database design. Consider if you did store the name of the category on the product table. Later down the line you then decided to change the name of the category, you would need to update all products records rather than just one category record.